# What makes the European XFEL the "fastest laser in the world"?

Tags: terminology, free-electron-lasers

I'm working in Hamburg so listening this morning to the local radio channels, all had been reporting about the "greeting call" to [DESY](http://www.desy.de/)  by different organizations pointing with their lasers to the [European XFEL](http://www.xfel.eu/en/) for getting public attention to it.

Almost all channels made a claim like "This is the brightest and quickest laser in the world" or "The biggest and fastest laser in the world".

The first time I heard it I was breaking out and laughed, I mean did they try to convince me it is FTL technique? But after every news I heard about it this morning kept making indications of being the word best laser in regards of speed, and me not being able to find any information about it in the Internet, I'm asking for help.

What measurement of speed is done for lasers, where XFEL will be the leading one in the world? I doubt it is the travel time of the light, so what else?

Comment: Highest energy laser maybe?

Comment: @JohnRennie: energy is a unit of movement? I'm not quiet sure what you try to tell me, sry.

Comment: I've been Googling and I can't find any support for your claim that the XFEL is being reported as the fastest laser in the world. The XFEL has the fastest pulse rate of any X-ray laser, and the electron beam is the highest energy so the electrons will be the fastest in any X-ray laser. At the end of the day I don't see how we can answer the question of how and why the media are using misleading descriptions.

Comment: This may be related to the pulse length of the laser pulses which is smaller than 100fs. But I am actually not so sure whether this is unique. What is unique is the combination of this short pulse length, the pulse frequency, and the small laser wavelength. This allows types of research that cannot be performed with other available experiments. See the comparison with other facilities: http://www.xfel.eu/overview/in_comparison and the overview of types of research that can be performed there: http://www.xfel.eu/research/possibilities/

Comment: @JohnRennie: Well actually answering that the media used misleading description IS an answer to this question. Well the source were multiple local radio channels. concrete "NDR Info" and "Radio Hamburg" both claimed in their news this morning it would be the fastest laser in the world.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about verifying unreferenced claims about equipment and not physics.

Comment: @KyleKanos This is a perfectly legitimate question about terminology and its use in describing physics experiments.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms in title.

Comment: @Qmechanic While European XFEL does indeed stand for 'European X-ray Free-Electron Laser', it is an institution name and it's best consumed in acronym form, in the same way that DESY nominally stands for Deutsches Elektronen-Synchrotron, but it's more helpful to call it by the former than by the latter. (That said, the name did stand some correction.)

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. Descriptions of E-XFEL as 'fastest' are perfectly reasonable and quite common, and OP's confusion about what 'fast' means is perfectly reasonable. Similarly, it's perfectly clear what the question was (i.e. "what does 'fast' refer to if not speed?"), as evidenced by the accepted answer. This thread should be reopened as-is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to FELs, 'fastest' tends to refer to the length of the pulse, i.e. you're not interested in the speed at which the pulse propagates (which is obviously always $c$), but at how short an interval of time you can compress the energy into, as the pulse passes some pre-established target.

In general, free-electron lasers are able to produce some of the shortest pulses of light available, but they do tend to suffer somewhat from temporal jitter, which means that the pulses' length and timing are not as consistent as you would like. (That then means that the shortest available pulses of light, which also have a higher timing stability, are produced via [high-harmonic generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_harmonic_generation), which strictly speaking isn't a laser, but a laser-driven parametric process.) The timing-jitter problem can be solved by providing the FEL with a 'seed': a low-energy pulse of light with a higher coherence and stability, that the FEL can then amplify. This can be done in one of two ways:

- one can use a pulse from an HHG source, which provides the best coherence properties, and which is currently only in use at the [FERMI](https://www.elettra.trieste.it/lightsources/fermi/machine.html) light source at the Elettra synchrotron in Trieste; or
- one can use a weaker FEL pulse as a seed, which the DESY team has been working on for some time and which they [recently started reporting](http://accelconf.web.cern.ch/AccelConf/ipac2017/papers/wepab016.pdf).

The news you heard refer to the opening of the European XFEL, which is [an improved version of the seeded FLASH facility](http://www.xfel.eu/overview/in_comparison) at DESY.

When it comes to the use of terms like "fastest", there's always a substantial amount of give in what does and doesn't count. As an example, single attosecond pulses produced via HHG can [go below the 70 attosecond mark](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nphoton.2013.362), much shorter and much more stable than seeded FELs (for comparison, the European XFEL specs claim pulses as short as 1 fs, though I would suspect there's significant timing jitter at that end of the range), but FEL people might want to dismiss them via technicalities ("they're not an actual laser") or on other figures of merit (FEL pulses are brighter) that make the comparisons that much more subjective. As such, it's normally safe to assume that when making those claims, the organization has bent some definitions so that they benefit them over their competitors.

Nevertheless, the sFLASH and European XFEL capabilities at DESY do represent a significant advance worth celebrating, and they do make us much more capable of producing short pulses (that are also useful in other aspects) than we were before them. That's what the 'fast' means in those news reports.

Comment: could be used for this https://www.technologyreview.com/s/428614/imaging-the-quantum-motion-of-electrons-using-light/ ? (see also the arxiv paper linked in the above)

Comment: @Zero That's extremely challenging science to do with an FEL - the pulses are much too long, and the pulse timing is too jittery - though I guess it could be done under some circumstances. For electronic motion, though, your best bet by far is via HHG. (Unless you're Fermi@elettra and you have an hhg-seeded FEL, of course.)